# Table of reference to variables in Lua

Tags: lua, reference, lua-table

I'm trying to keep track of various variables in a big Lua code base, for logging and analytics purposes.

Ideally I want to create a register function that registers an existing global variable and keeps a reference to that variable (can be anything from numbers, booleans or other tables) in a table.

This table will then be used to loop on and output the values of the registered variables at certain points of the execution.

I won't have control over what type of variables are used, and cannot change how those variables are setup. So I don't have the option of changing those variables to tables and such.

What would be the best approach in Lua?

Comment: Try setting *index* and *newindex* metamethods on `_G`.

Comment: How does that help with keeping the references with specific variables?
Say I want to keep the reference to Players.joined and Players.left, where Player is a global variable. And ignore all others.

Comment: Note that `.joined` and `.left` is inside `Player` table so `_G` only refers to it indirectly through `Player`. If you want `_G` to also keep a ref to those, you'll need to set up the plumbing yourself to get the behavior you're looking for. Using `__index` and `__newindex` gives you a way to hook into read/write events into `_G`. You can use that to create a sort of 'proxy' pattern to build on.

Comment: Perhaps you want to set *index* and *newindex* metamethods on `Players` then.

Comment: What is your idea of a "reference" here?

Comment: To have a reference to a table entry (which `Player.joined` and `Player.left` are) you need to store the table (`Player`) and the index (`"joined"` or `"left"`)

Comment: Alternatively you can create a wrapper so that if they index _G and get a table you return an identical table with the same metatable as that of _G set. This would recursively track everything.